# I am getting this error while executing update query in visual studio 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2012, sql-update

> Incorrect syntax near '='

my code is

```
"update staff_Tables 
 set emp_id='" + txtEmployeeID.Text + "' , 
     emp_sal='" + txtEmpSal.Text + "', 
     emp_name='" + txtEmployeeName.Text + "',
     emp_Deignation='" + txtDesignation.Text + "',
     Gender='" + cboGender.Text + "',
     contactno='" + txtContact.Text + "',
     Address='" + rtbAddress.Text + "',
     Joining_Date='" + txtjoindate.Text + "' 
 where txtid=" + txtid.Text, sqlcon.getCon());
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. I've edited your question to improve the format. Please read [ask].

Comment: what is the data type of emp_sal column

Answer (score 1):

First, you should never concatenate sql queries like this.
Your query is extremely vulnerable to [Sql Injectio](https://xkcd.com/327/)n attacks.

Always use either [stored procedures](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms345415.aspx) or [parameterized queries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb738521%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Second, did you try to debug? judging by the column names, `Emp_Id`, `Emp_Sal` and `contactno` are probably numeric data and not strings, therefor the ' surrounding the values is wrong.

Your query should look like this:

```
"update staff_Tables 
 set emp_id = @emp_id, 
     emp_sal = @emp_sal, 
     emp_name = @emp_name,
     emp_Deignation = @emp_Deignation,
     Gender = @Gender,
     contactno = @contactno,
     Address = @Address,
     Joining_Date = @Joining_Date 
 where txtid = @txtid"
```

and you add the parameter to the `SqlCommand.Parameters` collection like this:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@emp_id, SqlDBType.Int).Value = txtEmployeeID.Text
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably have a single quote in one of your .Text values, fix by doubling them up, example:

```
Address='" + Replace(rtbAddress.Text, "'", "''") + "' vb
Address='" + rtbAddress.Text.Replace("'", "''") + "' #c
```

But yes, you are open to sql injection with this method of updating database.